# Clearing chat using discord JDA

Tags: java, discord-jda

I am coding a discord bot in java, I use discord JDA, and the utilities dependency, I tried using the utilities one but I didn't get it to work, so I tried using just the normal JDA, this is what I did, but I need some way of telling the bot not to send the message in the new channel if the command wasn't ran.

```java
public class NukeCommand extends ListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event){
        if (event.getMessage().getContentRaw().equalsIgnoreCase(".nuke")){
            event.getChannel().createCopy().queue();
            event.getChannel().delete().queue();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChannelCreate(TextChannelCreateEvent createEvent){
        createEvent.getChannel().sendMessage(":warning:Nuked channel:warning:\nhttps://imgur.com/a/93vq9R8").queue();
    }
```

I am open for answers in both dependencies.
this is the effect I want: https://gyazo.com/e549fd8dda0ded62db19fb84e31d3a61
I have the same effect but it sends the message every time I create a text channel.
I want it to only send the message if the .nuke command was ran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution you can pass a consumable or whatever its called into the .queue method, this code gets run whenever the channel is created.
what i did:

```
    @Override
    public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event){
        if (event.getMember().hasPermission(Permission.MESSAGE_MANAGE)){
            if (event.getMessage().getContentRaw().equalsIgnoreCase(".nuke")){
                event.getChannel().createCopy().queue(channel->channel.sendMessage(":warning:Nuked channel:warning:\nhttps://imgur.com/a/93vq9R8").queue());
                event.getChannel().delete().queue();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You said you already got it but I though I'd explain more about how it actually  works and refine your answer.

`ListenerAdapter`'s methods are called for every event that happens in the whole scope of the bot, for example if you have

```
class Adapter extends ListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event){
       /*This will be called for every message, everywhere, including the bot's private channel*/
    }
}
```

So you need to filter those events inside the method's body, what you did on your answer was check if whoever sent the message has permissions to manage messages, which is not the one you actually need to delete channels, it is `Permission.MANAGE_CHANNELS`, you can find at the roles tab in your server.

Then you call `createCopy()` which basically creates a shallow copy of the channel's information
[image]

I don't think you actually wanted to do that.

Then you queue that action, (This is what actually executes it) it is put in a queue for asynchronous processing by JDA's threads, which will subsequently be sent to discord over the websocket connection.

That queue method can take a `Consumer<TextChannel>` as a parameter, what does that mean?

Basically a consumer represent an operation that takes a single parameter as input (In this case a `TextChannel`) and returns nothing. More about it here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html

The consumer you give in your answer is doing what you actually want to, sending the message, on the channel that was operated on by the previous queue, meaning that, `createCopy()` is completely useless, both `TextChannel` objects are the same, the appropriate would be:

```
event.getChannel().sendMessage(":warning:Nuked channel:warning:\nhttps://imgur.com/a/93vq9R8").queue();
```

After that, you delete the channel right away, which does not make that much sense, since most likely no one would even be able to see the nuked message.
For that, JDA provides another method for queueing tasks, this time with a delay:
`queueAfter()`
It takes a `long` as the value, and a `TimeUnit` object to specify what is the time unit of said value, for example:

```
event.getChannel().delete().queueAfter(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This would queue the task to be executed in 10 seconds, and it does NOT stop the execution of your code, unlike the `complete()` method.

Alternatively to that, you could just use `Thread.sleep()` which takes a long value as input: `Thread.sleep(10000)` for 10 seconds (10000 milliseconds).

You can find a lot more information regarding JDA and start tips and here: https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA#creating-the-jda-object

Comment: This is a nice explanation but the code i did works perfectly like i wanted it at least. This block of code basically clears all the chat(It deletes the channel because of discord purge method can only delete up to 14 days back) Then it writes nuked chat in the newly created channel. anyway nice post :D

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work (Without deleting the channel)

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NotNull MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        String message = event.getMessage().getContentRaw();

    if (message.toLowerCase().equals("$" + "clear")) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
            
            TextChannel channel = (TextChannel) event.getChannel();

            MessageHistory history = new MessageHistory(channel);
            List<Message> msgs;
    
            msgs = history.retrievePast(100).complete();
            if (msgs.size() > 1) {
                channel.deleteMessages(msgs).queue();
    
            } else {
                channel.sendMessage("Mensagens deletadas").queue();
                return;
            }

        }

    }`
```